# Why Is It Taking So Long, Numpy array filtration code?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code to filter large numpy array (6000000 rows) from zero rows.

```
nonZero_training_data=[]
for i in get_training_data:
    if (np.equal(i[0],[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]).all()):
        continue
    nonZero_training_data=nonZero_training_data+[i]
```

each row in array like this: 
    [(array([[x1,x2,x3,x4],
             [x1,x2,x3,x4]]), y),]

But the execution time is long, maybe takes a minute or more.

This is first 5 rows in get_training_data:

```
array([[array([[0.2, 0., 0., 0.],
       [0.9, 0., 0., 3.]]),
        1],
       [array([[0., 4., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.]]), 1],
       [array([[2., 0., 7., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 8.]]),
        0],
       [array([[0., 5., 0., 2.],
       [0., 8., 0., 1.]]),
        0],
       [array([[0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 5., 0., 0.]]),
        1]], dtype=object)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Sorry for my English, any correction I will appreciate.

Comment: What do you get if you print `type(get_training_data)`? If `get_training_data` is a numpy array, what do you get if you print `get_training_data.shape` ?

Comment: numpy.ndarray with shape (653580, 2)

Comment: Something is odd. You say that `get_training_data.shape` is `(653580, 2)`. In which case, in the loop `for i in get_training_data`, the value taken by `i` for each iteration would be a shape `(2,)` array, which cannot be compared to `[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]`.. Your code snippet should actually throw an error.

Comment: Thank you for your interest @fountainhead, but my code working without errors and tested many times

Comment: maybe you can give a small example of get_training_data, like the first 5 rows maybe.

Comment: get_training_data[0:5]=array([[array([[1,1,1],
       [1,1,1,1]]),
        1],
       [array([[1, 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]]), 1],
       [array([[1,1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0.00000000e+00, 1]]),
        0],
       [array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]]),
        0],
       [array([[1, 1, 1,1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]]),
        1]], dtype=object)

Comment: yes. include the output of that in your question so its easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on numpy, but apparently your goal is just to build a list by filtering some elements. You could achieve this using a list comprehension, which is both faster and shorter:

```
nonZero_training_data = [i for i in get_training_data if not (np.equal(i[0],[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]).all())]
```

In any case, it is not surprising that your code is slow: when you do this, you build and copy a new list every time you try to append an element:

```
nonZero_training_data = nonZero_training_data + [i]
```

which yields a quadratic time complexity. You should definitely experience improvements by replacing this with:

```
nonZero_training_data.append(i)
```

which appends the new element in place instead of building a new list then copying it to your variable.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. after testing list comprehension method and comparing it with my code execution time  it's faster 150 times than normal method.
normal method execution time: 646.59
list comprehension method execution time: 4.29
Knowing that my laptop processor model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz 2.90GHz

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that use only numpy, should be faster than list comprehension.

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(lambda x: not isinstance(x,int) and np.all(x[0] == [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]))
mask = vfunc(get_training_data)[:,0]

get_training_data[~mask]
```

Without vectorize:

```
mask = ~np.apply_along_axis( lambda x: np.all(x[0] == [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]), arr = get_training_data,axis= 1)
get_training_data[mask]
```

Comment: I tried both methods and noticed the difference in execution time. Most of the time the list comprehension method was a bit faster
Thank you for your interest @Christian Sloper

Comment: @MohamedOkasha Just for interest, can you measure the version without vectorize. I am interested to know if it is faster.

Comment: Thanks for testing

Comment: list comprehension method avg execution time after repeated 10 times : 4.627530264854431
mask with vectorize method avg execution time after repeated 10 times :5.701759672164917
mask without vectorize method avg execution time after repeated 10 times : 7.574653172492981